# Reload inline javascript after wordpress makes ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, call, reload

I have an issue and im hoping someone can help me out, here goes:

Using this tutorial: http://www.problogdesign.com/wordpress/load-next-wordpress-posts-with-ajax/ im able to dynamicly load posts without refreshing the browser!

So far so good!

I've even customized the code a bit and integrated it with jQuery Isotope.

So far so good!

A custom.js file has all the code in it along with a bunch of functions i created for prettyPhoto and a post liking script for example (prettyPhoto();, postlike();) wich i use in the 'load more' code so its 'reloaded' after posts get added.

So far so good!

Its done with the following code by the way:

jQuery( '#content .isotope' ).append($newEls).isotope( 'appended', $newEls, function() {

prettyPhoto();
postlike();

etc.

Creating functions so they can be used later on is no problem, now here is the real problem: i have a bunch of inline javascript for jplayer and flexslider for example wich i'm not able to reload after posts get added because i cannot create a functions wich i can use later on (as i did for prettyphoto and postlike) because the code for jplayer and flexslider are in a different file.

Jplayer uses the following code for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    if(jQuery().jPlayer) {
        jQuery('#jquery_jplayer_<?php the_ID(); ?>').jPlayer({
            ready: function() {
                jQuery(this).jPlayer('setMedia', {
                    mp3: "<?php echo stripslashes(htmlspecialchars_decode($mp3)); ?>",
                    oga: "<?php echo stripslashes(htmlspecialchars_decode($ogg)); ?>",
                    end: ""
                    });
                },
            swfPath: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jplayer/",
            cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_<?php the_ID(); ?>",
            supplied: "<?php if($mp3 != '') : ?>mp3, <?php endif; ?><?php if($ogg != '') : ?>oga, <?php endif; ?> all"
        });
    }

});
</script>
```

Notice that jPlayer is called using a unique identifier: #jquery_jplayer_

**My question is: how can i reload this "inline javascript" so it works after i dynamicly add new posts?**

I hope the above makes sence, if not id be glad to elaborate!

Edit:

```
    jQuery( '#load-posts a' ).live( 'click', function(e) {

        // Are there more posts to load?
        if(pageNum <= max) {

            // Show that we're working.
            jQuery(this).text( 'Loading...' );


                jQuery( '#content .isotope-new' ).load(nextLink + ' .item',
                function() {



                    var $newEls = jQuery( '#content .isotope-new .item' );

                    $newEls.imagesLoaded( function(){

                    jQuery( '#content .isotope' ).append($newEls).isotope( 'appended', $newEls, function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

First you're going to want to remove the old script to make sure you're not loading it twice. Give any scripts that you need to reinitialize a class:

`<script class="my-script">`

and

`$('.my-script').remove`

Then use `getScript`:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

The ajaxify.js script does a great job of doing this, so you can study its source code a bit to see how they do it: https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify on line 124, then on line 154

Comment: Thanks for your Awnser,

Where would i place the .remove code in the above edit?
Also cannot seem to work out how to use the getScript!

This is very frustrating because the inline javascript is the only thing thats not working!

Comment: Made some progress: jQuery( '.flexslider', this).flexslider(); initializes flexslider after new posts were loaded with AJAX. Only thing thats not working is jPlayer!